# tf.print prints nothing in IDLE in python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, printing, terminal, python-idle

Here is my environment:

- OS : MacOS Big Sur(11.4)
- Python Version : 3.7.2
- Tensorflow : 2.5.0

Run in IDLE:
[image: Run in IDLE]

Run in Terminal:
[image: Run in Terminal]

Please take look at two pictures I captured above. In IDLE environment, when I use `tf.print`, it doesn't print anything. However, if I run python from my terminal (under `bin` folder ..like % python3.7), then run the `tf.print` it prints correctly.

What could be the reason? I also tried installing Python 3.9.5, but I had exactly same behavior though.

Comment: Please replace the imgur images with the actual text shown,  Cut and paste it into you question and format as code so it displays properly.

Comment: `import sys; print('Hello', file=sys.stderr)` in IDLE prints 'Hello' with the stderr highlighting.  Please enter a number or string *without* importing tensorflow and report what happens.  It is possible that tensorflow replaces the sys.stdout and sys.stderr than IDLE installs, thus disconnecting the user code execution process for the IDLE GUI.  Or that tf.print does something IDLE does not expect.  I do know that tensorflow expected to be talking to a terminal program that acts differently from IDLE's GUI.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy I am not quite sure what you asked for. without importing tensorflow..ok..then I tried your example "Hello" in both IDLE and terminal...Of course, I can't use tf because tensorflow isn't imported, but I see 'Hello' in both IDLE and terminal..

Comment: BTW, I recall that tf.print Ive used and it worked,,though that was quite really long time ago...I just am starting using tf now because one of projects I am working on..and I just noticed this strange behavior.. hum...not sure this is due to some internal changes TF has made??..I really doubt it though....or some other python modules I installed could cause this issue??..I don't think so either..